# How do you use Valgrind/Helgrind on macOS?

Tags: c++, c, macos, debugging, valgrind

I'm learning C on a macOS machine, and having lots of issues with getting Valgrind to work, particularly with threading and Helgrind. It doesn't look like there's any support for this, which makes me wonder if:

1. Nobody develops C/C++ with macOS.
2. People do, but they don't use Valgrind/Helgrind.
3. There's a way to use Valgrind/Helgrind, and I just haven't figured it out.

Or am I missing something?

The best support for Valgrind I could find on macOS is [Valgrind for macOS](https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos), which doesn't support support threads/signals:

> using threads and signals is undefined

Comment: I don't use `valgrind` on mac but you can use `ASan`. `Clang` has other various sanitizers to find memory leaks and memory related bugs. FYI, Chrome/Chromium is written in C++/Obj-C++ for macOS and iOS, so maybe you can forget about point #1

Comment: On Xcode, _Address Sanitizer_ is readily available (can be selected under _Edit Scheme_). On my experience, _Address Sanitizer_ is nearly as powerful as Valgrind, while being maybe 10 times faster (or let's say, _less slower_).

Comment: 4. There aren't enough Valgrind/macOS developers.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has made a branch of Valgrind for use on MacOS (currently it doesn't work on M1/M2).

https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos